# Getting the sum of a variadic size_t... argument in a variadic template in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to create an n dimensional array template class (as a wrapper for `std::array` or c++ arrays) in c++ that allocates a single array block for the whole n dimensional array (To avoid the overhead of using n arrays with n indexes).

In doing this I want my template to be in the following format where `sizes` represent the size of each dimension.

```
template <class Type, size_t...  sizes>
class array_dimensional{
private:
    std::array<Type, /*here is the problem, how do 
       I get the product of all the sizes?*/> allocated_array;
...
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to get the product of all the sizes.

Is it possible to do this, and if so how?

Comment: Write a recursive multiply function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be one way to do it:

```
template<size_t size, size_t... sizes>
struct size_product
{
    static const size_t value = size * size_product<sizes...>::value;
};

template<size_t size>
struct size_product<size>
{
    static const size_t value = size;
};

...

std::array<Type, size_product<sizes...>::value> allocated_array;
```

Answer (score 8):

In C++14, a `constexpr` function may be easier to read:

```
template<size_t... S>
constexpr size_t multiply() {
    size_t result = 1;
    for(auto s : { S... }) result *= s;
    return result;
}
```

In C++17, just use a fold expression: `(... * sizes)`.

Comment: An example for how to use this would be helpful. It's not immediately obvious. Same for C++17.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on what your purpose for `dimensions` is, but I think this is what you're intended to do. You can accomplish this with a product-generating template that rips apart `sizes...` and pieces it back together via multiplication:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<size_t N, size_t... M>
struct product_of
{
    static constexpr size_t size = N *  product_of<M...>::size;
};

template<size_t N>
struct product_of<N>
{
    static constexpr size_t size = N;
};

template <class Type, size_t...  sizes>
struct array_dimensional
{
    static std::array<size_t, sizeof...(sizes)> dims;
    std::array<Type, product_of<sizes...>::size> ar;
};

template<class Type, size_t... sizes>
std::array<size_t, sizeof...(sizes)> array_dimensional<Type,sizes...>::dims{sizes...};

int main()
{
    array_dimensional<int, 2,3,4,5> ar;

    std::cout << ar.dims.size() << '\n';
    for (auto x : ar.dims)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << ar.ar.size() << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
4
2 3 4 5 
120
```

Note: I've made zero affordances for zero detection nor for overflow. Regardless, I hope it helps.

Best of luck

Comment: `dims` can still be `constexpr` as an `std::array` too, afaik.